# How to style MUI TreeItem component in my own Theme?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, treeview, themes

I want to assign colors to MUI TreeItem component. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641151/styling-selected-treeitem-inside-a-treeview) but I want to do it using [Theme style overrides](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#theme-style-overrides) in my own Theme. But I can't because TreeItem not in standard components list (but in '@mui/lab').

I tried to write section using [this instruction](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#theme-style-overrides) but it generate an error: "*TS2322: Type '{ MuiTreeItem: {}; }' is not assignable to type 'Components<Omit<Theme, "components">>'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'MuiTreeItem' does not exist in type 'Components<Omit<Theme, "components">>'.*"

How can I include TreeItem colors into my Theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following line:

```
import type {} from "@mui/x-tree-view/themeAugmentation";
```

Full working example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { TreeView, TreeItem } from "@mui/x-tree-view";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

import type {} from "@mui/x-tree-view/themeAugmentation";

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTreeItem: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "& > .MuiTreeItem-content.Mui-selected": {
            color: "red",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export default function FileSystemNavigator() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <TreeView
        aria-label="file system navigator"
        defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
        sx={{ height: 240, flexGrow: 1, maxWidth: 400, overflowY: "auto" }}
      >
        <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="Applications">
          <TreeItem nodeId="2" label="Calendar" />
        </TreeItem>
        <TreeItem nodeId="5" label="Documents">
          <TreeItem nodeId="10" label="OSS" />
          <TreeItem nodeId="6" label="MUI">
            <TreeItem nodeId="8" label="index.js" />
          </TreeItem>
        </TreeItem>
      </TreeView>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/treeview-theme-customization-sn6w94?file=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.tsx%3A15%2C26

- Related documentation: https://mui.com/x/react-tree-view/#typescript
- Related question: [Styling selected TreeItem inside a TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641151/styling-selected-treeitem-inside-a-treeview)

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working "just what the doctor ordered" :)

Comment: After transfer TreeView from lab to x-... this solution stopped working. MuiTreeItem not found in 'component' part. Can you recommend some working solution? Thank you!

Comment: @user I've updated the example to use MUI-X instead of the lab